# What is the largest n-way tie possible for Mario Kart?

Tags: optimization

In a $12$ player race, the scoring system of Mario Kart awards $15$ points for 1st place, $12$ for 2nd, then $13-x$ for $3\leq x\leq 12$. A standard cup is $4$ races. What is the largest $n$ such that an $n$-way tie is possible?

For example, a $4$-way tie is trivially achievable by having the four best racers achieve 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th once each. A $12$-way tie is trivially impossible, as the total points available is not divisible by $12$.

---

Optional extra: Can this be generalized to any point distribution/number of racers/number of races? Not required for accepted answer, but I'm curious to know.

(Full disclaimer, I don't know the answer)

Comment: What for x>12 - 0 points? or is that not allowed. "12 is trivially impossible" suggest all players should tie, is this the intent. If not: Are we talking a tie for first place, or is any tie  allowed (I get to a 22-way tie for last place, even infinite for scoring 0, but assume that is not what you want)

Comment: Indeed, like @Retudin asked: can we tie for last (or any other) place? or only for first place?

Comment: @Retudin there are never more than 12 competitors in a race

Comment: Note that the scoring is different in different entries in the series; prior to mario kart 8, you couldn't even have 12-person races, with 8 being the maximum.

Comment: I have an intuition that the generalized case is NP-hard. By some reduction from subset-sum or something like that, maybe.

Comment: @Retudin Thanks for the suggestion, edited the question to clarify. I intended 12 players per race

Comment: @Hearth there aren't even 12 characters in the first game; there were only 8.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

An 11 way tie is possible:

> 11 players score 28: 
>  4 players finish 1st, 3rd, 11th and 12th: 15 + 10 + 2 + 1 = 28 
>  4 players finish 2nd, 4th, 9th and 10th: 12 + 9 + 4 + 3 = 28 
>  2 players finish 5th twice and 7th twice, : 8 + 8 + 6 + 6 = 28 
>  1 player finishes 6th in each race: 7 + 7 + 7 + 7 = 28 
>  with last place finishing 8th in each race: 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 20

Comment: The possible common scores in an $11$-way tie turn out to be $25, 26, 27, 28, 29$.

Comment: @RobPratt Sounds interesting, can you elaborate? I'd like to know how you found those

Comment: An 11-way tie where the common score isn't 25..29 is at least impossible, since the non-common score is either negative or above 60 (which requires more than 15 per round). And for 25..27 it will not be a tie for the win. But I don't know if they are achievable.

Comment: @HansOlsson They are all achievable.

Answer (score 10):

Here’s how to do a $10$-way tie:

> - Four racers achieving 1st, 5th, 9th and 10th for a total of $15+8+4+3=30$ 
>  - Four racers achieving 2nd, 4th, 6th, and 11th for a total of $12+9+7+2=30$ 
>  - Two racers achieving 3rd and 8th twice, for a total of $10+5+10+5 = 30$ 
>  - Two racers achieving 7th and 12th twice, who tie last with a score of $6+1+6+1=14$

Answer (score 6):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For $j\in \{1,\dots,12\}$, let $p_j$ be the points awarded for place $j$; that is, $p_1=15$, $p_2=12$, and $p_j=13-j$ otherwise.  For $i\in\{1,\dots,12\}$, $j\in \{1,\dots,12\}$, and $k\in\{1,\dots,4\}$, let binary decision variable $x_{ijk}$ indicate whether player $i$ places $j$ in race $k$.  Let decision variable $s_i$ be the total score for player $i$, let decision variable $c$ be the common score, and let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether $s_i=c$.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_i y_i$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{ijk} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$ and $k$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_i x_{ijk} &= 1 &&\text{for all $j$ and $k$} \tag2\label2 \\
\sum_{j,k} p_j x_{ijk} &= s_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag3\label3 \\
-15(1-y_i) \le s_i - c &\le 15(1-y_i) &&\text{for all $i$} \tag4\label4
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} assigns one place to each player and race.
Constraint \eqref{2} assigns one player to each place and race.
Constraint \eqref{3} enforces the definition of $s_i$.
Constraint \eqref{4} enforces the logical implication $y_i=1 \implies s_i=c$.

The optimal objective value turns out to be $11$, achieved for example by the following outcomes (each race $k$ yields a permutation of $\{1,\dots,12\}$):
\begin{matrix}
i & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & s_i\\
\hline
1&1&7&7&12&28\\ 2&2&12&2&10&28\\ 3&3&1&12&11&28\\ 4&4&11&11&1&28\\ 5&5&5&10&4&28\\ 6&6&10&9&7&20\\ 7&7&3&8&6&28\\ 8&8&2&6&9&28\\ 9&9&9&1&8&28\\ 10&10&6&5&3&28\\ 11&11&4&4&5&28\\ 12&12&8&3&2&28
\end{matrix}

To find the range of possible common scores $c$, impose an additional constraint
$$\sum_i y_i = 11$$
and minimize or maximize $c$.  The range turns out to be $25 \le c \le 29$, and all five values are achievable.

Here's a solution with $c=25$:
\begin{matrix}
i & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & s_i\\
\hline
1&1&10&9&10&25\\ 2&2&11&11&4&25\\ 3&3&9&12&3&25\\ 4&4&5&7&11&25\\ 5&5&1&1&1&53\\ 6&6&4&5&12&25\\ 7&7&12&2&7&25\\ 8&8&8&6&5&25\\ 9&9&7&10&2&25\\ 10&10&2&8&8&25\\ 11&11&3&4&9&25\\ 12&12&6&3&6&25
\end{matrix}

Here's a solution with $c=29$:
\begin{matrix}
i & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & s_i\\
\hline
1&1&6&8&11&29\\ 2&2&9&9&4&29\\ 3&3&7&6&7&29\\ 4&4&5&4&10&29\\ 5&5&1&11&9&29\\ 6&6&2&10&6&29\\ 7&7&12&12&12&9\\ 8&8&4&3&8&29\\ 9&9&11&1&5&29\\ 10&10&10&5&1&29\\ 11&11&8&2&3&29\\ 12&12&3&7&2&29
\end{matrix}

Comment: Can you list down the scoring for the 25 and the 29 score? That's something interesting since it's the lowest and highest possible score in the 11-way tie.

Comment: There are numerous solutions (and not that to make by hand) so 'the' scoring does not really exist.

Comment: @justhalf I added solutions for 25 and 29 just now.